# How to use an interpolation argument to prove $A\hookrightarrow L^p(\mathbb R)$ for $p\in [2, +\infty]?$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, interpolation

Assume you have that
$$A\hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb R) \quad\text{ and }\quad B\hookrightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb R).$$
Suppose also that $A\hookrightarrow B$.
By using the above information, is it possible to prove that
$$A\hookrightarrow L^p(\mathbb R)\quad\mbox{ for all } p\in [2, +\infty]?$$

I asked the lecturer, and he said that it can be proved by using an interpolation argument.
What does it mean? Anyone could please help me with the proof?

Comment: What does the notation $\hookrightarrow$ mean? Anyway, for a function $f$, if $f \in L^2(\mathbb R) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, then for any $p \in [2,\infty]$, $\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^p dx \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^{p-2}\int_{\mathbb R} |f|^2 dx$, so $f \in L^p(\mathbb R)$. If that's what you need to solve this question then great!